# Why does G-d desire the prayer of the righteous?

Tags: tefilla, theology, rashi

If I am not mistaken, I believe that Rashi comments that the reason that G-d made the patriarchs and matriarch not have children until an old age was because he desired their prayers.

If G-d is perfect and doesn't need or lack anything why then does he desire the prayer of the righteous?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Since G-d is Omnipotent Why Does He Need Our Prayers?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5967/1368)

Comment: @TamirEvan Maybe, but maybe not...is there something special about the prayers of the righteous, more so than they prayers of everyone else?

Comment: @Shokhet That is a good question (and maybe should be asked separately), but the OP is asking _vis-a-vis_ God's perfection (omnipotence?), which should be the same as the other question, regardless of the quality of the one praying. As I said, "possible" - not "definite" - duplicate.

Comment: @TamirEvan I hear your point, but I don't know how central that point is to the OP's question. `@AniYodea, you might want to think about how you could [edit] your question to make the difference (if there is one) between your question and the proposed duplicate apparent

Answer (score 1):

What HASHEM wants is his children to be good. Prayer, true heartfelt prayer, from someone that gives their all in the "right" path is pleasing to the Almighty as a child or pet's behavior will bring a smile to parent/owner. I believe this to be the case, I could be wrong though.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodea! A source would greatly  enhance the value of this interesting answer.